# Numpy arrays getting objects instead of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im using Python3.6 with numpy library last release and when im calling a function i made:

```
    def matriz_jacobiana_reducida(self, a, b, c):
    return np.array([
        [-c * np.sin(a) * np.cos(b) - c * np.cos(a) * np.sin(b) - self.a1 * np.sin(a),
         -c * np.cos(a) * np.sin(b) - c * np.sin(a) * np.cos(b),
         np.cos(a) * np.cos(b) - np.sin(a) * np.sin(b)],
        [-c * np.cos(a) * np.cos(b) - c * np.sin(a) * np.sin(b) + self.a1 * np.cos(a),
         -c * np.sin(a) * np.sin(b) + c * np.cos(a) * np.cos(b),
         np.sin(a) * np.cos(b) + np.cos(a) * np.sin(b)],
        [1, 1, 0]
    ])
```

On the third iteration of a loop Im starting to get something weird instead of values inside the numpy matrix:

```
[[array([1.85417763]) array([-0.14528501]) array([0.99970679])][array([6.04488775]) array([5.99824076]) array([0.02421417])][1 1 0]]
```

I tried to copy the values into another array but didnt work and when im calling this array i start getting errors:

```
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc det
```

Whats the reason behind this [array(value)] format numpy is setting?

Thanks.

Comment: `self.a1`, `a`, `b`, or `c` appear to be arrays instead of single scalars.

Comment: Exactly this, user235112, i was calling theta back as an array and not as a float type.


Thank you, been struggling for hours with this!